# Spotfire Map Chart - Show markers only in the highlighted(selected) area

Tags: spotfire

I am a beginner in Spotfire.

I have lat long coordinates of employee work and home location.

Here is what i have done so far.. on one marker layer I have marked the coordinates of all work locations and on other marker layer, I have marked home coordinates of all the employees.

What i want to show initially on the map are only the Work locations and when the user selects any area on the map near any work location, then only the employees whose home locations are in that selected area should display.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to check if you already have the zip code along with those lat and long values if no then download it from google,  if yes then do the following steps:

1. Add the data table and rename it as a work location.
2. Show on the map only the Work locations using a marker layer.
3. Add the same table again and rename it as a home address.
4. Go to **Edit** - **Data Table Properties** - **Relations** and join
       both the tables using the ***Zip code***.
5. Right-click on Map and **Create a details visualization** -
   **Table** -  using the Home address data table and select the required columns.

Now once you mark any records on the map you would be able to see the details of the home address of the colleagues overlapping on that zip code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work too much with Maps but you may want view this Tibco Example :

https://community.tibco.com/modules/points-polygons-data-function-tibco-spotfire